# Could we make it easier to find questions we haven't accepted an answer to?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, unanswered-questions

A long time ago, I learned that the URL
`https://<S.E site>/search?q=user%3A<my user numbe>+closed%3A0+hasaccepted%3A0+answers%3A1+wiki%3A0&submit=search` (user:XXX closed:0 hasaccepted:0 answers:1 wiki:0) shows all of my questions on a S.E site which I have not yet answered.

I imagine that lots of users would not know of this and how to do it for their own questions, would like to know it, and would like it to be simpler to do.

Would it be possible to add something like a button on my profile page, visible only to me, obviously, to show this? I don't really care how it is implemented, so long as it is easily accessible. If possible, I would like it both per site and S.E-wide.

Or did I miss something, and this is already available?

Not sure if it's for everyone, but I would be happy with a nagging email ("you haven't answered that question that you asked X days ago").

Comment: Did you substitute the site name and ***your*** user number? This works for me. Even if it i wrong, which I doubt, I am not asking for the correct URL; I am asking for an easy to use button where anyone can check for their own unanswered questions, no matter the underlying code,

Comment: Yes, I missed out the user number, the same results can be done using search: user:44619 closed:0 hasaccepted:0 answers:1 wiki:0

Comment: I tried `https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A44619+closed%3A0+hasaccepted%3A0+answers%3A1+wiki%3A0&submit=search` and got `user:44619 closed:0 hasaccepted:0 answers:1 wiki:0` What do yout think? I believe that it would greatly help increase the number of accepted answers.

Comment: If I didn't accept any of those answers there was a good reason...but maybe some would find this "trick" helpful. Not my DV but I would be really really annoyed by a nagging email by SE, even if it was a polite nudge. Extremely annoyed.

Comment: Is this about self answering unanswered questions or accepting answers? You can already sort-of  'easily' see which of your questions have an accepted answer on your profile: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/146759/mawg-says-reinstate-monica?tab=questions > The ones with a solid green square have an accepted answer, the ones with only green outlines have an answer but not an accepted one yet.

Comment: Couldn't you just visit your profile page and set it on [**questions**](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/44619/mari-lou-a?tab=questions)? At a glance you would see which questions had been accepted or not.

Comment: Here's a shorter way, go to your profile page, in the search box type `user:number hasaccepted:no`

Comment: @Mari-LouA I can't see all of my questions on a single screen. Also, thanks for the shorter way. I still think that a button would make it more obvious and make people more likely to answer questions. Perhaps a button sort option on the questions page? And what about S.E wide, as a bonus?

Comment: How much screen have you available?

Comment: `user:me answers:0` should work.

Comment: And, it does. But I still can't see newbies sing it. Hmmm, 9 downvotes, I guess means that 9 people don't like the idea. A pity that none of them could be bothered to explain why. I honestly believe that we could get newbies & the lethargic accepting more answers, if we made it easier.

Answer (score 2):

It is already quite easy to do this.  There is a dropdown menu in the search box when you click it; one of the things it shows is how to show *unanswered questions.*  It also shows how to search by user, so just type in the search box:

```
user:me answers:0
```

And it should show your unanswered posts.  To see your accepted answers:

```
user:me hasaccepted:no
```

As for not seeing all your unanswered posts in a single screen, if you have a lot of posts, you will need a very big screen.